# Mock Objects: implement interface or extend class?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In a library I'm writing, I'm wanting to write unit tests. I know in order to truly have a unit test, only one object can be tested a time.

My question pertains directly to creating mock objects. I'm writing an XML library to convert PHP arrays into well-formed XML, and I decided to solve the inclusion of attributes by creating a container object. I don't foresee a reason to write an interface for the class other than to create a mock version of it.

Is it better to write an interface merely to mock an object, especially when the interface would only have getters? Or is the solution to extend the base class and either set the data members or override the getters to return specific values? Or is there a third solution I have not considered?

Thanks.

Per SenseException's suggestion, here's the object structure:

EXMLWriter: Takes an EXMLData object and, runs validators, and writes XML.

EXMLData: The `$data` is an array where `$key => $value` is used to generate the XML.

```
interface iEXMLData {
    public function getData();
    public function getRoot();
    public function getRuleset();
}
```

EXMLRuleSet: Container class for a set of EXMLValidators. Basically an array with function to run each validator.

EXMLValidator: Runs whatever checks against EXMLData's $data member.

```
interface iEXMLValidator {
    public function validate($data);
}
```

EXMLElement: A special class that EXMLWriter knows about to allow the use of attributes XML. Literally `getData()` and `getAttributes()`.

In the EXMLWriter class, I've added this type of logic:

```
if(is_array($value)) {
    //code
}
elseif($value instanceof iEXMLData) {
    //code
}
elseif($value instanceof EXMLElement) {
    //code
}
```

Because EXMLElement is just getters and setters for data, it doesn't make sense to have it interfaced.

Comment: Actually you test even smaller parts of an object: one method. Do you have any examples to show how your object structure look like?

Comment: What I meant was that the tests interact with one object. I'll edit my question to include some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phpUnit [`getMock`](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html) method can be used on a class.

***ClassToTest.php***

```
<?php
class ClassToTest {}
```

***TestClassToTest.php***

```
<?php
require './ClassToTest.php';

class TestClassToTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMocks()
    {
        $oMock = $this->getMock('ClassToTest');
        $this->assertTrue($oMock instanceof ClassToTest);

        $oC = new ClassToTest();
        $this->assertTrue($oC instanceof ClassToTest);
    }
}
```

***Running phpUnit***

```
PHPUnit 3.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.25Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but it caused any `instanceof` checks to fail.

Comment: That's pretty strange.., I believe get mock makes the mock a subclass of the class being mocked. I might test it myself just to verify.

Comment: It's possible I had made a mistake there. When I ran into the problem, I just created a mock object, but that was for a different project.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested, it works fine. I'm going to paste my code into the answer for reference.

Comment: It's not quite the same context of what I meant, but I'll try it regardless. Your code suggests that it should work; it's likely I did something incorrectly on the other project.

Comment: If it fails, PHPUnit cannot load the code of the original class when creating the mock. That means you also cannot create a real instance of the original class - try it.

Comment: Looks like PHPUnit throws an exception if it fails. I'd imagine that would be bad. Anyway look at [the docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html). You *should* be able to mock a class. Per the link: `getMock($className)`.